# Помогите разобраться с MySQL, удалил таблицу, как востановить?

Tags: mysql

При попытке восстановить удаленную при помощи DELETE таблицу, при помощи
mysql> LOAD XML INFILE '/home/vavan/JAWA/MySQL/mysqlExports/city.xml' INTO TABLE
city;
выдает ошибку ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
В гугле толком не нашел, только понял, что надо избавиться от этого файла --secure-file-priv, а как не понимаю?
P.S. У меня убунту 20.04
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот где-то здесь я так понимаю надо вставить secure-file-priv = ""

Comment: *В гугле толком не нашел* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Comment: я вот тоже не могу найти